# Importing CSV into pandas with one column that contains all column names and another containing all the values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

I want to import a CSV into pandas. I currently use a for loop and turn the CSV into a dictionary before turning it into a data frame.

The data looks like this:

```
| row id | attr name | attr value |
| ______ | _________ | __________ |
| 5      | beans.    | 1.         | 
| 5.     | fruit.    | 2          |
| 5.     | claw.     | 2          |
| 5.     | house.    | 1          |
| 5.     | nuts.     | 0          |
| 6.     | beans.    | 0          |
| 6.     | fruit.    | 1          |
| 6.     | claw.     | 2          |
| 6.     | house.    | 3          |
| 6.     | nuts.     | 0          |
```

And I want it to look like this:

```
| row id | beans | fruit | claw | house | nuts |
| ______ | _____ | _____ | ____ | _____ | ____ |
| 5.     | 1     | 2     | 2    | 1     | 0    |
| 6.     | 0     | 1     | 2    | 3     | 0    |
```

Is this at all possible to do automatically? Or should I just stick to my for loop that reads it in row-by-row?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to do is to [reshape the frame](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/reshaping.html#reshaping). You can achieve this through a pivot

```
df.pivot(index="id",  columns="name", values="value")
```

Comment: Accepted this one as an answer, because the other answer includes square brackets around the columns and values, which changes the output. I had to add df.attr_name = pd.Categorical(df.attr_name, categories = df.attr_name.unique(), ordered=True) to ensure that the attr_names would stay in order and not be sorted alphabetically

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
df.pivot(index='row id', columns=['attr name'], values=['attr value'])
```

https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).